# Spring AOP vs @Transactional annotation

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I want to implement transaction using Spring's transaction management feature. But I'm not sure which is better(AOP vs @Transactional). Do both features work correctly? Is there any difference in development efficiency?

---

(Added)
Here AOP means "using AspectJ without using @Transactional annotation explicitly"

---

(Added)
 I want to know difference of annotation-config and XML-based configuration

Comment: Your question makes no sense to me. The `@Transactional` annotation uses Spring AOP to implement the transaction management. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Here AOP means "using AspectJ without using @Transactional annotation explicitly"

Comment: Why do you ever need to compare AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) with the annotation `@Transactional`?

Comment: using your own aspects instead of spring provided ones to do excaclty the same work would be like reinventing the wheel a bit

Comment: I assume, firia2000 would like to know what is better for the transaction management: annotation-config or XML-based configuration. Am I right?

Comment: @LaurentG yes, you are right. I want to know difference of annotation-config and XML-based configuration

Comment: They are exchangeable(both does the same) the + of XML: all the transaction conf is in one place. The + of annotation: you can determinate faster if one method is transactional or not(easier for reading).

Answer (score 3):

I've wondered this myself.  I found a good discussion of this topic on the [Spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/115866-spring-declarative-transaction-which-is-better-aop-vs-transactional-support).

Below I've summarize my take from the aforementioned link:

#### AOP Transactional Demarcation

Benefits:

- Java code is devoid of transaction configuration which is contained instead outside of the code in configuration files
- Java code has no direct dependencies on Spring libraries
- Transaction management is centralized in one place
- Can apply transactional boundaries to source code you can't easily modify

Drawbacks:

- AOP complexity. It will not be clear from the code alone where transactional boundaries lie and developers may inadvertently break transactions by, for example, modifying method signatures where a pointcut is applied
- The need to touch two locations (source code and AOP configuration) in order to apply transactional boundaries

#### `@Transactional` Spring annotation

Benefits:

- Transactional boundaries are more clearly understood when examining the source code

Drawbacks:

- Java code is coupled with transaction declaration (albeit only at the metadata level, but still a Spring import is required).

---

The discussion reminds me of JPA annotations versus JPA XML configuration.  With XML based JPA configuration, entities are "cleaner", but is the separation worth the effort?  Or perhaps even, is the separation harmful (it's nice to be able to open a java source file and know immediately based on the @Entity annotation that the class is an EJB)?  In practice, it seems to me that most developers opt to use JPA annotations.  Although, in this case unlike `@Transactional`, jpa annotations are a standard so that may help ease some concerns.

That said, I've been involved on projects were we've used Spring's AOP configuration to annotate a Struts2 (webwork) interceptor to allow a single transaction per request and this worked out great.  In this case, we didn't really worry about transactional boundaries in our service layer or elsewhere -- everything was already participating in a transaction and since the view rendered before the interceptor closed the transaction, there was no need to apply an `OpenSession/EntityManagerInView` solution.